# como puedo evitar que se autocomplete un TexBox al presionar un Button sin funciones

Tags: c#, asp.net, navegador-web

Tengo un formulario que al cargar la página, se rellena con datos, mi idea es después reemplazar los datos actuales por los ingresados nuevos, pero haciendo unas pruebas, y agregando un Button sin ningún funcionamiento, me reescribe nuevamente los campos, ya sea estando vacíos o cuando escribo dentro del TexBox, pero al presionar el botón se completa nuevamente, desconozco si es tema del navegador o algo que hago está mal.

protected void btnModificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

```
    }



<div class="input-field col s10">

     <asp:Button ID="btnModificar" CssClass="btn-large btn-block black center-block" runat="server" Text="Modificar" OnClick="btnModificar_Click" />
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

if (Session["login"] != null)
                {
                    Usuario usuario = (Usuario)Session["login"];

```
                string nombreCompleto = usuario.nombreCompleto();
                Master.navSet.Text = "Bienvenido: " + nombreCompleto;
                Master.ocultarLi = Visible;

                txtUsuario.Text = usuario._usuario;
                txtNombre.Text = usuario._nombre;
                txtApellido.Text = usuario._apellido;
                txtRut.Text = usuario._rut;
                txtCorreo.Text = usuario._correo;
                txtContraseña.Text = usuario._contraseña;

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
            }
```

}

Comment: Podrias poner tu **Code Behind**? o por lo menos el **load** Al hacer click estas generando un postback. No lo debes estar manejándolo bien en el load.

Comment: disculpe, acabo de adjuntar el Page_Load, de los datos que se escriben en el TextBox al iniciar la pagina

Comment: abajo de dejé la solución. Es un error típico al comienzo. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al hacer click en el boton y tener asignado un evento en el servidor, por mas que no ejecutes codigo dentro de `btnModificar_Click`, estas generando un [Postback](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postback). Ahora, el problema debe venir en el **Load**. Seguramente estas cargando ahí tus datos en los campos. Lo que debes hacer es siempre verificar que el codigo se ejecute solo cuando se carga por primera vez la pagina y evitar repetir estas acciones en un posback(Puede pasar que necesites repetir algunas). Lo que vamos a hacer es usar [Page.IsPostBack Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.ispostback?view=netframework-4.7.2) para validar esto.

Tu load debería quedar con la siguiente estructura:

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Aquí voy a ejecutar todas las acciones 
        //que correspondan solo cuando se carga por primera  vez la pagina.
    }else{
           //Solo las acciones que correspondan a un postback
    }

    // El resto de las acciones que se deben ejecutar siempre.
}
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos!